# Invalid Column in NHibernate Map-by-Code ComponentAsId

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-3

I have the following table

tblChild

FatherCode
   ChildNumber
   Name

`FatherCode` and `ChildNumber` are the primary keys of the table.

Since something like this happens very often in this database (I have ZERO control over it), I created the following class for me to map the Id:

```
public class ComposedId {
   public virtual int FatherId {get;set;}
   public virtual int ChildId {get;set;}
   //More code implementing Equals and GetHashCode
}
```

Now, the mapping goes like this:

```
aMapper.Class<Child>(aClassMapper => aClassMapper.ComposedId(aComposedIdMapper =>
                {
                    aComposedIdMapper.Property(aChild => aChild.Id); //Id's implementation is: public virtual ComposedId Id {get;set;}
                }));

aMapper.Class<Child>(aClassMapper => aClassMapper.ComponentAsId(aChild => aChild.Id, aComponentAsIdMapper =>
    {
        aComponentAsIdMapper.Property(aComposedId => aComposedId.FatherId, aPropertyMapper => aPropertyMapper.Column("FatherCode"));
        aComponentAsIdMapper.Property(aComposedId => aComposedId.ChildId, aPropertyMapper => aPropertyMapper.Column("ChildNumber"));
    }));
```

But when I'm try to query the table, NHibernate tries to get the Id as a column.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, and I tried a lot of ways to map this with this structure, but nothing works :(

Comment: Have you tried commenting the first mapping? It looks like it's messing the second mapping statement.

Comment: BTW, what mapping strategy is this? I've seen HBM and Fluent, but this one I don't recognize.

Comment: This is Loquacious, if from NHibernate 3.3, and it's like their own Fluent. This is one of the problems.. is kind of a new thing, so there's isn't much on the internet

Comment: It looks so... dirty. I like Fluent better. No way to change?

Comment: I'd rather not, since this ways is native to NHibernate.
And I didn't find it ugly(maybe the aMapper.Class<Child> thing is abit awkward, but this is my fault and not NHibernate's). 
Besides, we're not here to argue wich technology is better, I just have to make this work :)

Comment: Not at all, it was just a random idea =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line in your mapping is incorrect.

I used this, which is just a simplified version of your code:

```
mapper.Class<Child>(cm => cm.ComponentAsId(
    x => x.Id,
    caim =>
    {
        caim.Property(x => x.FatherId, pm => pm.Column("FatherCode"));
        caim.Property(x => x.ChildId, pm => pm.Column("ChildNumber"));
    }));
```

And it correctly generated this mapping (XML-serialized):

```
<composite-id class="ComposedId" name="Id">
  <key-property name="FatherId" column="FatherCode" />
  <key-property name="ChildId" column="ChildNumber" />
</composite-id>
```

...which in turn produces correct SQL.

You say in the comments that you tried without the first line, but you probably forgot to compile, deploy or restart a server when testing it.

As a side note, if you rename the properties of `ComposedId` to match the db and use `ConventionModelMapper`, you don't even have to map the Id manually.

---

To get the XML mapping I use this:

```
var mappingDocument = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
new XmlSerializer(typeof(HbmMapping)).Serialize(Console.Out, mappingDocument);
```

Comment: The problem is that I want the ComposedId class to be a generic structure for these kind of situations, I'm gonna try this again and tell you the results.
By the way, how do you see the xml generated by NHibernate?

Comment: And another thing... would this work if ComposedId was ComposedId<int,int> (in this case, it'd be a generic class that takes the types of it's two attributes. It's what i actually have here, i just omited for the sake of simplicity)

Comment: See added block for XML serialization. It works just fine with a generic ComposedId; the XML is ugly because of the CLR syntax, but you don't have to deal with it so it's not a problem.

Comment: HOHO OH WOW! It actually worked. Maybe I forgot to clean something before trying. Thanks dude :) And thanks for the XML thing

Comment: Man, actually it didn't work... i tried with Repository.GetAll().Count() and it ran fine, but when I use Repository.GetAll().ToList() it keeps complaining that ID doesn't exist

:(

Comment: Also tried taking out the generics from my ComposedId class(to make it like the example i posted) still same error.

Comment: Ok, got it yo work... apparently you have to map the component first, and then you can use it as the Id, i've edited your aswer so I can accept it. Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: @Tejo, your change generates exactly the same output. Please verify and post the XML with and without the change.

Comment: Yeah, so.. With the change, it generates the XML you posted, without it, NHibernate tries to map the properties to the ID field, that doesn't exist.. it probably is a bug

Comment: There has to be something *else* that you are doing with the mapper to cause that. Maybe some convention...

Comment: This is a Special case, if my class has a ComposedId, I don`t use convention in them. I think it's probably a bug, dunno.. this can't be the default behavior, and i'm sure i'm not doing anything else :(

Comment: This is not working when you have multiple classes, the ComposedId was shared between classes... any tip?